# Trying to capture raw_input to use later

Tags: python, input

I am trying to make a def function that uses ra_input, and the data is to be used outside the function. The function is to be called many times.

```
var1=""
var2=""
theresult=""
def getstuff():
    theresult = raw_input("Enter your result")
print "Here is the result:"

print theresult
```

no result appears.
Tried return, and tried return(), and tried return result, and tried return(result),
anyone help??
Also why the box below unformatted when I type the question??

Comment: There's an orange question mark above the preview window when you [edit] or write the question. It can help with formatting.

Comment: You are very helpful and fast. Thanks for being there and best of luck to you and your carreer!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way would probably be:

```
def getstuff():
    return raw_input("Enter your result")

theresult = getstuff()
print theresult
```

Another option would be to use `global`, but I don't think it would be justified here.

Comment: Lev you saved my sanity.been trying for months to solve this..hundreds of (wrong)lines of programming!

Answer (score 0):

Here are codes that should do the job.

> def getstuff():
>
> ```
> theresult = raw_input("Enter your result:  ")
> return theresult
> ```
>
> def main():
>
> ```
> var1 = " "
> var2 = " "
> ```
>
> theresult = getstuff()
>
> print "Here is the result: "
>
> print theresult
>
> main()